# Command tcpdump and traceroute

Tags: networking, bash, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I have a problem about linux terminal using WSL from Windows, I need to use networks commands like tcpdump, traceroute, etc, but for any of their I have a positive answer, for example, in tcpdump command appear this message: socket for SIOCETHTOOL(ETHTOOL_GET_TS_INFO): Socket type not supported and in the traceroute command I don't have any answer, only appeared asterisks.
I'd like to know if the problem is some network setting because the basics commands works well. How can I solve this?